# Are there any techniques for streamlining a mathematical model?

Tags: problem-solving, mathematical-modeling, signal-processing

I have a model I'm working on and would like to present. Mathematics is not my main field and while I work with enough statisticians to know my model is reasonable, it seems clunky. It's in a format I haven't seen presented before and I suspect there is some way to remove the two double summations. Can anyone point me towards references or examples of how to streamline an equation like this?

$\text{Value of Signal} = \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{Id} (\sum_{n=1}^{Io} O_v  O_{\%})  (\frac {S + S_c - S_d} {S_t} ) \bigg) - \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{Is} (\sum_{n=1}^{Io} E_{icost}  E_{o\%})  (P_b  R_v) \bigg)$

Comment: The first thing would be to stop abusing the notation by using the same index variable for two sums that cover the same scope. When you actually show the dependence of your variables on $n$, how would anyone know which $n$ you are referring two, where there are two $n$s in use?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll make that change. Io must be changed as well, which I am embarrassed to say refers to two separate (ontologically related) variables, I've just spotted.

Comment: You missed it. You still have a summation over $n$ inside another summation over $n$, twice. Another problem is that we cannot see if various possibilities for simplification are usable because we don't know which if any of the $O, S, E, P, R$ variables depend on the indexes.